# How do I display the following in python?

Tags: python, loops, nested, iteration

The problem statement is:

> Write a function `create_grid` that takes in the number squares on a side and the number of stars on a side of a square then returns the grid of squares as a string. Separate each line by the newline (`\n`) character.

it should display the following:

```
assert_equal(
    create_grid(1, 1),
"""+ - +
| * |
+ - +
""")
assert_equal(
    create_grid(2, 4),
"""+ - - - - + - - - - +
| * * * * |         |
| * * * * |         |
| * * * * |         |
| * * * * |         |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
|         | * * * * |
|         | * * * * |
|         | * * * * |
|         | * * * * |
+ - - - - + - - - - +
""")
assert_equal(
    create_grid(4, 2),
"""+ - - + - - + - - + - - +
| * * |     | * * |     |
| * * |     | * * |     |
+ - - + - - + - - + - - +
|     | * * |     | * * |
|     | * * |     | * * |
+ - - + - - + - - + - - +
| * * |     | * * |     |
| * * |     | * * |     |
+ - - + - - + - - + - - +
|     | * * |     | * * |
|     | * * |     | * * |
+ - - + - - + - - + - - +
""")
```

I have only been able to come up with the following code:

```
def create_grid(num_squares, num_stars):
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    #raise NotImplementedError()

    #'+ - +\n
    #| * |\n
    #+ - +\n'
    holder = ""
    a = '+ ' + "- "*num_stars + "+\n"
    b = '| ' + '* '*num_stars + '|\n'

    for squaresdown in range(num_squares):
        holder+=a
        for row in range(num_stars):
            holder+=b
    holder+=a
    print(holder)

create_grid(3,5)
```

which displays the grid

```
+ - - - - - +
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
+ - - - - - +
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
+ - - - - - +
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
| * * * * * |
+ - - - - - +
```

How do I implement a way to:

- Ignore putting stars every other box
- generate new columns?

Comment: Please retake the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You're asking for individualized help, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  "I can't understand the logic" asks for reading comprehension; "should this be implemented ..." asks for design advice.  There are many ways to implement this; which method to use depends on your comfort level -- out of scope here.

Comment: For a bit of help, however, I can perhaps clarify the function parameters.  Your function is supposed to return a game board, like a chess board of arbitrary size.  The first parameter gives you the overall board dimension in squares; a chess board would have an `8` in this position, because it's an 8x8 board.

Comment: The second parameter is the size of each square: how many stars or spaces are in each direction.  If you want a relative large chess board, so you can do ASCII-art pieces in the squares, you might want, say, 7x7 stars / spaces in each square.  You would call your routine with (8, 7) in this case.

Comment: You are not using the `num_squares` parameter in your function.

Comment: Can you come up with a math rule that tells you how far apart the + signs go? Can you come up with a math rule that tells you how many times to draw lines with +s in them, and how many lines to put in between them? Can you come up with a math rule that tells you whether or not to draw stars inside a square?

Comment: @Prune thank you for this. That was truly what I meant. I will take a look into that to ask better questions

Answer (score 0):

Consider this approach (Updated):

```
def create_grid(num_squares, num_stars):
    holder = ""
    a = '+ ' + ("- " * num_stars + "+ " + "- " * num_stars + '+ ')*(
        num_squares // 2) + ("- " * num_stars + "+ ") * (num_squares % 2)
    b = ('| ' + '* ' * num_stars + '| ' + "  " * num_stars)*(num_squares//2) \
         + ('| ' + '* ' * num_stars) * (num_squares % 2)

    for column in range(num_squares):
        holder += a + "\n"
        for row in range(num_stars):
            holder += (b + '|' if (column % 2) == 0 else '|' + b[::-1]) + "\n"
    holder += a + "\n"
    print(holder)
```

Therefore, some illustrative examples of how it prints:

`create_grid(1,1)`:

```
+ - +
| * |
+ - +
```

`create_grid(1,2)`:

```
+ - - +
| * * |
| * * |
+ - - +
```

`create_grid(1,3)`:

```
+ - - - +
| * * * |
| * * * |
| * * * |
+ - - - +
```

`create_grid(2,1)`:

```
+ - + - +
| * |   |
+ - + - +
|   | * |
+ - + - +
```

`create_grid(2,2)`:

```
+ - - + - - +
| * * |     |
| * * |     |
+ - - + - - +
|     | * * |
|     | * * |
+ - - + - - +
```

`create_grid(2,3)`:

```
+ - - - + - - - +
| * * * |       |
| * * * |       |
| * * * |       |
+ - - - + - - - +
|       | * * * |
|       | * * * |
|       | * * * |
+ - - - + - - - +
```

`create_grid(3,1)`:

```
+ - + - + - +
| * |   | * |
+ - + - + - +
| * |   | * |
+ - + - + - +
| * |   | * |
+ - + - + - +
```

`create_grid(3,2)`:

```
+ - - + - - + - - +
| * * |     | * * |
| * * |     | * * |
+ - - + - - + - - +
| * * |     | * * |
| * * |     | * * |
+ - - + - - + - - +
| * * |     | * * |
| * * |     | * * |
+ - - + - - + - - +
```

`create_grid(3,3)`:

```
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
| * * * |       | * * * |
| * * * |       | * * * |
| * * * |       | * * * |
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
| * * * |       | * * * |
| * * * |       | * * * |
| * * * |       | * * * |
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
| * * * |       | * * * |
| * * * |       | * * * |
| * * * |       | * * * |
+ - - - + - - - + - - - +
```

Comment: Thank you! How come though when it is a 1,1 grid, it show's differently from what is expected?

Comment: Sorry, @matmatpancakes, I did not consider odd numbers. I have already fixed the function and put some examples.